# Why does this inequality involving a $2$-norm and trace hold?

Tags: matrices, inequality, matrix-equations

The inequality is as follows:

$$\left\| {\bf{h}} {\bf W}^\top \right\|_2 + \text{Tr}\left(\frac{({\bf W}^\top)^H{\bf{h}}^H{\bf{h}}}{\|{\bf{h}}\bf{W}^t\|_2}\left({\bf W} - {\bf W}^\top \right)\right)\leq\|{\bf h} {\bf W}\|_2,$$

where ${\bf W}^t \in \mathbb{C}^{L \times L}$ and ${\bf h} \in \mathbb{C}^{1 \times L}$ are known. So I wonder why this inequality holds?

Comment: @RACHpreamble What is the motivation for this question?  Where does this come from?

Comment: Do you mean: **Problem**: Let $W_0 \in \mathbb{C}^{L\times L}$ and $h\in \mathbb{C}^{1\times L}$ be given.
Let $W \in \mathbb{C}^{L\times L}$.
Prove that
$$\|hW_0\|_2 + \mathrm{Re}\left[\mathrm{Tr}\left(\frac{W_0^\mathsf{H}h^\mathsf{H} h}{\|hW_0\|_2}(W  - W_0)\right)\right] \le \|hW\|_2.$$
It is written as
$$\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{hWW_0^{\mathsf{H}}h^{\mathsf{H}}}{\|hW_0\|_2}\right)\le \|hW\|_2.$$
Then use $\mathrm{Re}(z) \le |z|$
and C-S inequality.

Comment: Many thanks! I understand!